# Spinner And Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I am using spinner and listview concurrently, I have some logic that when i scroll on list i have have a data indication that tells which values to set on spinner, and i m using

```
spinner.setSelection(somePosition);
```

and when I click on Spinner it has also some data which indicate that to set the position of

```
listView.setSelection(somePosition);
```

Problem is that when i m scrolling on listView and in my adapter i need to change the postion of spinner selected item it calls the method

```
spinnerSurah.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int clickPosition, long l) {
                int skipTotal = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < clickPosition ; i++)
                {
                    SafeJSONObject surahObject = jsonArraySurahList.getJSONObject(i);
                    skipTotal+= surahObject.getInt("ayas");
                }
                SafeJSONObject surahObject = jsonArraySurahList.getJSONObject(clickPosition);
                Log.e("spinnerSurah","spinnerSurah surahObject "+surahObject.toString());
                positionSelection = skipTotal;
                listView.setSelection(positionSelection);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Help me, I need to just change the postion of spinner without calling its listener.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a condition in your listener that bypasses the selection logic if the ListView selection is called from the listener.

Declare a boolean in your class:

```
boolean skip_listener = false;
```

and change your listener to

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int clickPosition, long l) {
                if(skip_listener){skip_listener = !skip_listener;return;}
                int skipTotal = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < clickPosition ; i++)
                {
                    SafeJSONObject surahObject = jsonArraySurahList.getJSONObject(i);
                    skipTotal+= surahObject.getInt("ayas");
                }
                SafeJSONObject surahObject = jsonArraySurahList.getJSONObject(clickPosition);
                Log.e("spinnerSurah","spinnerSurah surahObject "+surahObject.toString());
                positionSelection = skipTotal;
                skip_listener = true;
                listView.setSelection(positionSelection);


                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks It works to some extent , and now i have another question how i can apply onTouchListener and onClicKListener on Button  ? e.g I need to swipe button functionality and clickable too on the same button

Comment: In addition to button click, you can detect touch events such as touching down the button with MotionEvent.
Add `import android.view.MotionEvent` and then add touch listener to button:
`button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                    //Add your touch action here
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });`